# What all command can be given using rsh?

Tags: rsh, rshd

What commands can be given from an rshd server to an an rsh client? Only file transfer commands or commands such as run a command i.e python xyz.py command can also be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsh username@fullyqualifieddomainname python home/user/pathtocode/
```

This is I could run using rsh.

rsh can be used to run any command whichever you want and there is no restriction of which kind of commands that can be used. 
normally

```
rsh username@FQDN
```

command if we are not specifying the command it uses rlogin to log into the system, this needs password authentication.
for secured networks compared to ssh rsh is better(according to me because in one particular situation I found it useful, if any user needs details of how it can be useful then ping me I am ready to help.